# How to get decoded url to download a file on Django?

Tags: django

URL='http://localhost:8765/app/download/?file=/path/to/download/my%3Afolder/file_signed_django.xml'

I'd like to know how to deal with this URL, i'm trying to download this file (Signed by Django), the problem is when it changes ':' to '%3A', don't know how to get rid of it, i'm using Django 1.9.13

Thank you so much

Comment: How do you handle this right now? Normally `request.GET` will do the decoding for you.

Comment: i'm getting the path of this file by this way and retrieves with '%3A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY, I did some changes at the model (Because I cannot deal with it on views.py, cause it's signed and definitely cannot be changed). Let me show you my code:

```
@staticmethod
def fix_path(path):
    if ':' in path:
        return path.replace(':','')
    return path
```

That's what i've added on my class, you can do whatever, but only at the modal

Answer (score 1):

Use urllib.unquote to decode %-
`urllib.unquote(url)`

Try this and comment, wheather it works for you.